# C# get class member result caching

Tags: c#, performance

Does C# cache the value for a class member if the result doesn't change? So does C# store the value for `Area` after it is calculated and simply return it as long as `X` and `Y` aren't changed or does the first example calculate `X * Y` for each `Area` get call? Or in other words, are the examples below equally (from a computational view point) performant?

```
public double Area => X * Y;
private double X { get; set; } = 5;
private double Y { get; set; } = 5;
```

---

```
public double Area { get; }

public Rectangle(double x = 5, double y = 5)
{
   Area = x * y;   
}
```

Comment: In the use case you have provided, both solutions will perform the same with no measurable performance difference

Comment: The chances that you could measure a difference here are vanishingly small. Don't fall into common traps of thinking that every piece of code must perform as fast as possible or that you can just learn a "simple" set of rules that will allow you to always achieve the best performance. Clear, understandable code that performs adequately is almost always the best choice unless or until you have *measured* some code and compared that against a set of *goals* to establish that you have a performance problem to solve.

Comment: Why do you care whether the runtime caches calculated values? This smells like an X-Y problem, what is your concern around calculated properties?

Comment: Caching does not come without cost, especially you need to care about cache invalidation. In this simple case it is unlikely that caching would have any benefit at all, and in the general it is unlikely that the compiler or the runtime has enough information to automatically insert the caching code for you.

Comment: If the input is constant, the jitter could in theory do inlining and constant propagation to avoid any runtime calculation. But it any non-trivial case the jitter would have difficulty proving that the parameters did not change between calls, and the .Net jitter is fairly limited in the optimizations it will perform.  But multiplication is fast, so do not worry about it unless you have measurements to show that it actually affects speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the IL code generated by your class.

https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhMA9gK4BGEApgQIIBObAhgQC8APgIANAgCoCATQDcVGgAduYAG59gHBi3biKBAOZtgcggGcTZgL5CCAVgXYaBFes3amrDjIPHTFlYEtoIOTi74pAAUOt4EAB5QBLF6AJ4AlBSKLtQSofHhOdS+oamF1NY41kA===

Class:

```
public class C {
    public double Area => X * Y;
    private double X { get; set; } = 5;
    private double Y { get; set; } = 5;
    public C(double x, double y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Generated IL code for Area:

```
  .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance float64 get_Area () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 14 (0xe)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance float64 C::get_X()
        IL_0006: ldarg.0
        IL_0007: call instance float64 C::get_Y()
        IL_000c: mul
        IL_000d: ret
    } // end of method C::get_Area
```

And as you can see - 2 getters are called and `mul` multiplication call is executed.

You can also take a look at `JIT Asm` part at the same link. And basically no, no cache will be injected for that property, in this case it depends on the runtime. Runtime might apply some performance optimizations but that will not be the case.

If you convert Area to getter and assign a value to it in constructor - yes, it will require less instructions for reading.

```
    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance float64 get_Area () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld float64 C::'<Area>k__BackingField'
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::get_Area
```